# Get all data for the next 24 hours from selected date in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get all data for the next 24 hours from selected date. I don't want to pull any data that is before 3/12/2015 but I need all data for the next 24 hours from this date 3/12/2015. I know I have to self join the table but not sure how to do this. The query below pulls the last 24 hours from the selected date but I need the opposite, the next 24 hours. Please help

```
select 
    mt1.ID, mt1.Name, mt1.FullDateTime
from 
    myTable mt1
inner join 
    myTable mt2 on mt1.FullDateTime between DATEADD(hour, -24, mt2.FullDateTime) and mt2.FullDateTime 
                and mt2.selectedDate = 3/13/2015
```

Comment: Post your sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Why is there a join? Why not just this (MySQL style):  select ID, Name, FullDateTime 
from my Table
where FullDateTime between '2015-03-13 00:09:00' and '2015-03-14 00:08:59'

Comment: `i know i have to self join the table` - why do you know this?

Comment: Without a time component the next 24 hours from 3/12/2015 is just 3/12/2015. Really you need self join?  Learn some basic TSQL.  You are just guessing and posting questions,  And not even good questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Use
[Date ADD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186819.aspx)

E.G:

```
DECLARE @SelectedDate datetime
SET @SelectedDate = getdate()

select dateadd(hour,24,@SelectedDate)
```

Your Query should be like.

```
DECLARE @SelectedDate date
SET @SelectedDate = '2015-03-15 15:05:20.533'
SELECT ID, 
       Name, 
       FullDateTime
FROM myTable 
WHERE FullDateTime>=@SelectedDate AND FullDateTime<=DATEADD(hour,24,@SelectedDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use any join.
try this:

```
DECLARE @SelectedDate date
SET @SelectedDate = '3/13/2015'

SELECT ID, 
       Name, 
       FullDateTime
FROM myTable 
WHERE FullDateTime BETWEEN @SelectedDate AND DATEADD(HH, 24, @SelectedDate)
```